# Inverse of a self-adjoint operator

Tags: linear-transformations, inverse, adjoint-operators

Let $A \colon \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{k}$ and $B \colon \mathbb{R}^{m} \to \mathbb{R}^{k}$ be two bounded linear operators. Denote
$$ V \colon \left( x , y , z \right) \mapsto \left( \left( \dfrac{1}{s} - rA^{*}A \right) x + \dfrac{r}{2} A^{*}By , \dfrac{r}{2} B^{*}Ax + \left( \dfrac{1}{t} - rB^{*}B \right) y , \dfrac{1}{r} z \right) . $$

The question is

> Under which condition $V$ is invertible and find $V^{-1}$

I can show that $V$ is a self-adjoint operator and when
$$ 0 < t < \dfrac{2}{3r \left\lVert A \right\rVert ^{2}} , 0 < s < \dfrac{2}{3r \left\lVert B \right\rVert ^{2}} $$
it is $\rho-$strongly positive therefore $V^{-1}$ exists. The remain part is to find its inverse. I don't know how to find it. I tried to cheat by consider $A$ and $B$ like a matrix instead of operator then we can rewrite
$$ V = \begin{pmatrix} 
\dfrac{1}{s} - rA^{T}A & \dfrac{r}{2} A^{T}B & 0 \\
\dfrac{r}{2} B^{T}A & \dfrac{1}{t} - rB^{T}B & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{r} I
\end{pmatrix} $$
but it leads to nowhere and I also not sure that it is an appropriate way...

Answer (score 2):

It's neither cheating nor inappropriate, just using block matrices.  First of all, the inverse will be of the form
$$ \pmatrix{M^{-1} & 0\cr 0 & r I}$$ where $M$ is the block matrix
$$ \pmatrix{1/s - r A^T A & r A^T B/2\cr r B^T A/2 & 1/t - r B^T B\cr} $$

Now use the $2 \times 2$ [block matrix inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion)

Comment: many thanks for your suggestion! do you mean that next time when ever I want to inverse a linear operator, I can always do similar as when I inverse a matrix?

Answer (score 2):

One can rewrite $V$ as identity plus 'rank one' as:
$$
V = \pmatrix{ s^{-1}I && \\& t^{-1}I & \\&& r^{-1}I&&} - r\pmatrix{A^T\\B^T\\0}\pmatrix{A&B&0} \\
= \pmatrix{ s^{-1}I && \\& t^{-1}I & \\&& r^{-1}I&&} \left( I -
r\pmatrix{\sqrt s A^T\\\sqrt t B^T\\0}\pmatrix{\sqrt s A&\sqrt t B&0}  \right)
$$
Then one can apply the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity).

Comment: thank you so much. very nice technique. just for sure do you think the Woodbury matrix identity still valid when I consider operator instead of matrix. I mean in general a linear operator can be infinite dimensional

Comment: This formula is still valid provided all the inverses exist.